# I keep getting request timeout when trying to ping a server, could it be my fault?

Tags: server, ping

A client we are working with has opened their ldap server for me to connect to to troubleshoot some errors. Specifically, they have a server, and then a port for me to connect to.

When I try to ping this server I am getting a constant request timeout, and when asking the client they said I should be able to ping it with the credentials they gave.

My understanding is that they need to let me in or it is an issue on their end, right? I should be able to ping any server I can connect to?

Or is this something I need to fix on my end? Could it be firewall issue?